# Is there a difference in speed between tf.keras.Model subclass implementation and equivalent tf functional API implementation?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras

Let's assume we have two equivalent models which have the same inputs, layers and outputs, except one is implemented as a tf.keras.Model subclass, and the other is implemented in the tf functional API. Is there a difference in the speed of inference or training of these models?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference between two. You can check the Keras document of functional API here: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

or here the same tf.keras version: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

They both are the same and will give you a model that works in exactly same way.

Comment: Both of these links seem to refer to the functional API. I know that the outputs of both implementations will be the same, but I am wondering if subclassing tf.keras.Model is slower...